# How can we generate C8 coverage report on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, code-coverage

We have a nodejs app running on Heroku. We are trying to generate coverage report using C8, however since Heroku has an ephemeral file system, C8 is unable to generate the coverage report or any files/folders. Is there a way by which we can execute C8 on Heroku and generate the coverage report?